# Using xacro for robot description does not work

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, roslaunch, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I defined a model using the urdf and everything works fine. However, when I replace one of the links with a macro, the link is not built to form the tree.

the xacro file: links_joints.xacro`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:macro name="m_link_box" params="name origin_xyz origin_rpy size">
    <link name="${name}">
      <!--<inertial>
        <mass value="${mass}" />
        <origin rpy="${origin_rpy}" xyz="${origin_xyz}" />
        <inertia ixx="${ixx}" ixy="${ixy}" ixz="${ixz}" iyy="${iyy}" iyz="${iyz}" izz="${izz}" />
      </inertial>
      <collision>
        <origin rpy="${origin_rpy}" xyz="${origin_xyz}" />
        <geometry>
          <box size="${size}" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>-->
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="${origin_rpy}" xyz="${origin_xyz}" />
        <geometry>
          <box size="${size}" />
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

`

Using this file works: mrm.xacro`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="mrm" xmlns:xacro="https://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">


  <xacro:include filename="$(find mrm_description)/urdf/links_joints.xacro" />
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0 "/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1 1 1"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
    <joint name="base_link__link_01" type="revolute">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit effort="0.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.5"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="link_01"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="link_01">
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2 "/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.35" length="0.4" />
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
</robot>
```

`

But replacing first link with the macro fails to build the tree:
`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="mrm" xmlns:xacro="https://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">


  <xacro:include filename="$(find mrm_description)/urdf/links_joints.xacro" />
    
    <m_link_box name="base_link"
              origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0"
              size="1 1 1" />

    <joint name="base_link__link_01" type="revolute">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit effort="0.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.5"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="link_01"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="link_01">
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2 "/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.35" length="0.4" />
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
</robot>
```

`

I am using rviz to visualize the urdf. The error says "Failed to parse URDF". Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388844/using-xacro-for-robot-description-does-not-work/) by [nj08](https://answers.ros.org/users/53346/nj08/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-16**:
Use `check_urdf <urdf file name>` to check for errors first.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-16**:
Check this [tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File) and one observation there are less chances to have errors if you use the open and close tags, as it make it easier to find if something is missing.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-16**:
In the first example that 'works' you are not using macro, the xacro:include even if it doesn't work it's not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the parsing issue is that you have no whitespace around your open and close xml comment tags.

Separate from the above, the modern syntax to create an instance of a macro is `<xacro:m_link_box name=...>`, but for backward compatibiiity the older style is still supported.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nj08](https://answers.ros.org/users/53346/nj08/) on 2021-10-18**:
`<xacro:m_link_box name=...>` worked. Thank you